# Постоянно выдает ошибку при попытке чтения/открытия файла в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

При попытке открытия файла постоянно выдает различные ошибки. Один раз все получилось когда я прописал encoding='utf-8', но теперь опять ничего не работет. Также VS Code подсвечивает первый символ после знака '' в ссылке на файл

Поправка. Вот текст ошибки

```
PS D:\JoJo\goose> & C:/Python/python.exe d:/JoJo/goose/ballance/files_to_edit/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/JoJo/goose/ballance/files_to_edit/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    f = open('C:\py_tests\new_text.txt', encoding='utf-8')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\py_tests\new_text.txt'
```

[image: В ссылке на файн VS Code выдеяет \n в C:\py_tests\new_text.txt другим цветом]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что ваша строка

```
'C:\py_tests\new_text.txt'
```

в параметре функции `open()` не интерпретируется так, как бы вы хотели.

В ней находится пара знаков `\n`, и она интерпретуриется как 1 знак - переход на новую строку.

Примените нормальные слеши (`/`) и все будет в порядке:

```
f = open('C:/py_tests/new_text.txt', encoding='utf-8')
```

Да, и в Виндовсах.